# Accessing Resouce image in Visual Studio 2015 - specifically location path

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2015

I'm creating an Excel addin project using Visual Studio Tools For Office (VSTO) in visual studio 2015.  I have to add/include the company logo -- a .png file to this addin.  I added the logo image file to the Visual Studio Resources.  I tried the following using the image in the VS Resources to include in the addin -- which did not work

```
var myLogo = Properties.Resources.CompanyLogo;
myWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(myLogo, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, 10, 20, 250, 40);
```

I received an error message that myLogo needed to be in string format -- like a file path format.  So I tried the following which did work -- but ..... this just seems a little kludgy.  I have to include using System.IO, ....

```
var outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
string myLogo = outPutDirectory.Substring(6, outPutDirectory.Length - 6) + @"\CompanyLogo.png";    

myWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(myLogo, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, 10, 20, 250, 40);
```

I also included CompanyLogo.png file to the root folder of my addin project and I set it to copy to the output directory every time I compile the project.  So, the 2nd routine here ***DOES*** work, but I'm thinking I should/would like to use the file located in the Project Resources section.  How can I retrieve a file path for my Companylogo.png resource from Project.Resources?

If this is not possible -- what is the point of having/using the Resources Property of Visual Studio?  I just think I'm missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem I was having with the method above was that it was kind of static.  Well, I finally figured out how to use the Resource property to make it less static:

```
Image img = Properties.Resources.CompanyLogo;
var outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
img.Save(outPutDirectory + @"\CompanyLogo.png", ImageFormat.Png);
myWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(outPutDirectory + @"\CompanyLogo.png", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, 0, 0, 260, 50);
```

Now I can save the png wherever the assembly is executing instead of hardcoding some path.

But I do have one other question which is on the resource file build action -- there is the none option, never copy, copy always, embedded resource, resource, ....
I tried each of these options which did not appear to make any difference (and I deleted the png from destination location first each time).  I left the build action as Resource for "just in case".  I am open for suggestions on the build action types.